# MySql sort within sorted results set

Tags: mysql, sorting, set

I have the following query which queries a table of sports results for the last 20 matches that involved a teams, returning goals conceeded in each of these matches.

```
SELECT *, `against` AS `goalsF` , `for` AS `goalsA`
FROM `matches` , `teams` , `outcomes`
WHERE (
`home_team_id`=7 AND `matches`.away_team_id = `teams`.team_id

OR 
`away_team_id`=7 AND `matches`.home_team_id = `teams`.team_id
)
AND `matches`.score_id = `outcomes`.outcome_id
ORDER BY `against', `date` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

I want sort the results by goals conceeded and then within each group of goals conceeded by date so for example.

the first 4 results where goals conceded=1 in date order
then the next 3 might be results where conceded=2 in date order

I have tried `ORDER by date,against` - this gives me a strict date order
I have tried `ORDER by against,date` - this gives me matches beyond the last 20

Is it possible to do what I want to do?

Comment: Consider starting again, with just a clear and concise "sqlfiddled"[http://www.sqlfiddle.com/] data set, AND the result set you'd expect from your query.

Comment: Also (and related), I'm not sure those ANDs and ORs are working in quite the way you might expect - but I might be wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I found this worked. This solution was posted by another user but then was removed, not sure why?

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, `against` AS `goalsF` , `for` AS `goalsA`
    FROM `matches` , `teams` , `outcomes`
    WHERE (
        `home_team_id`=7 AND `matches`.away_team_id = `teams`.team_id
        OR 
        `away_team_id`=7 AND `matches`.home_team_id = `teams`.team_id
    )
    AND `matches`.score_id = `outcomes`.outcome_id
    ORDER by `goalsF`
    LIMIT 0 , 20
) res
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Comment: I have a further question on refining the result but I will start another question...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to limit by date, add the date range you are looking for into your WHERE clause and then order by the number of goals conceded.

Comment: I don't know the date range specifically, I just need the last x matches which will always be a variable date range.